# how to add ck editor in dhtmlxgrid instead of mce editor

Tags: ckeditor, dhtmlx

i have added ck editor in dhtmlxgrid, this.event is getting call when user clicks on link->target tab or user left mouse click on link dialog.When user clicks on ok button in target tab error on console is 'Cannot read property 'getSelection' of undefined'

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the issue cannot be reproduced locally. Could you provide a link to the demo-page, where the problem can be reconstructed?